# does any one know of a better method for timed event

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i want to click a delete button once a week i tried using set time out but got nothing so i used a cron job which worked but effected the code so that when i navigated away from the page and back again it had cleared all of my inputs that i didn't want cleared i used this code

```
const cronJob = new CronJob('0 2 * * 0', () => {
  
  this.deleteBtn1.nativeElement.click();
});

if (currentDay === 0) {
  
  const currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
  if (currentHour >= 2) {
    
    this.deleteBtn1.nativeElement.click();
  } else {
    
    cronJob.start();
  }
} else {
  
  cronJob.start();
}
```

is there a better method i can use or can anyone see whats wrong with this code

sorry first time on this site order of questions may be incorrect using ionic frame work and angular